# How to open XUL application in private (incognito) mode?

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I am working on a XUL application. I want to open cookie free app on start just like Private Window. I used

```
pref("network.cookie.lifetimePolicy", 2);
```

But this seems to be not working at all.
Is there any other method to achieve this?

Comment: Does setting the `pref("browser.privatebrowsing.autostart", true);` help?

Comment: Thanks for your response but  It isn't working.
 Actually on closing app the cookies destroy successfully. if app is open I logged into some site, the cookies will maintan until I close the app, but If I app is open and I run another instance(app) and visit same site, It detecting the cookies/session and logged in automatically. I want to cookie free start on every instance, no matter how many instances are already running